# How to automatically capture \prevgraf value (inside xparse environment) every time text ends with \par?

Tags: tex-core, paragraphs, expl3, xparse

I need to declare an environment with `\NewDocumentEnvironment` such that every `\par` provided by the user inside that environment would automatically set an integer variable (inside environment-declaration code) to `\prevgraf` value. But for some reason `\prevgraf` is always zero when it's inside `\everypar` (in environment-declaration code). Of course I can do `\par\int_set:Nn\myNum{\prevgraf}` (in user-text provided to the environment) but I cannot have anything else there following `\par` (user is not allowed to directly use code in the text to set internal `\myNum` value).

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N\myNum % THIS SHOULD HOLD LAST \prevgraf
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{+b}
  { \parbox{\hsize}
      { \everypar
          { % simply display \prevgraf value (in red)
            \textcolor{red}
              { \bf\the\prevgraf\newline
              }
             % capturing prevgraf here doesn't work because prevgraf is always zero
             \int_set:Nn\myNum{\prevgraf}
          }
        #1 % DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT CONTENTS
      }
  } {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{myEnv}
  When PNG development started in early 1995, developers decided
   not to incorporate support for animation, because the majority
    of the PNG developers felt that overloading a single file type
     with both still and animation features is a bad design.
      \par % WE CAN CAPTURE HERE MANUALLY BUT WE WON'T,
       %  BECAUSE WE NEED TO CAPTURE AUTOMATICALLY WITH \par ALONE
  PNG supports palette-based images (with palettes of 24-bit RGB or
   32-bit RGBA colors), grayscale images (with or without alpha channel
    for transparency), and full-color non-palette-based RGB/RGBA images
     (with or without alpha channel).
      \par % WE CAN CAPTURE HERE MANUALLY BUT WE WON'T,
       %  BECAUSE WE NEED TO CAPTURE AUTOMATICALLY WITH \par ALONE
\end{myEnv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Both `\prevgraf` values after `\par` are actually 4, not 0. Why are they zeros, and how to capture the real values without adding any code after `\par`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems: First, `\everypar` is executed at the beginning of every paragraph, after the paragraph already started.
Because the paragraph already started, `\prevgraf` is no longer set.
Instead you can redefine `\par` to save the value. Then you have to save the value first before adding any output, otherwise your `\textcolor` starts a new paragraph and resets `\prevgraf`.

Independent from the actual problem you shouldn't use `\bf` with LaTeX. Use `\textbf{...}` or `\bfseries` instead.

For example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N\l__my_int % THIS SHOULD HOLD LAST \prevgraf
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{+b}
  { \parbox{\hsize}
      { \cs_set_eq:NN \__bp_preserved_par: \par
        \cs_set:Npn \par {
          \__bp_preserved_par:
          \int_set:Nn \l__my_int { \prevgraf }
          \textcolor{red}
            { \textbf
              { \int_use:N \l__my_int \newline
              }
            }
        }
        #1 % DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT CONTENTS
      }
  } {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{myEnv}
  When PNG development started in early 1995, developers decided
   not to incorporate support for animation, because the majority
    of the PNG developers felt that overloading a single file type
     with both still and animation features is a bad design.
      \par % WE CAN CAPTURE HERE MANUALLY BUT WE WON'T,
       %  BECAUSE WE NEED TO CAPTURE AUTOMATICALLY WITH \par ALONE
  PNG supports palette-based images (with palettes of 24-bit RGB or
   32-bit RGBA colors), grayscale images (with or without alpha channel
    for transparency), and full-color non-palette-based RGB/RGBA images
     (with or without alpha channel).
      \par % WE CAN CAPTURE HERE MANUALLY BUT WE WON'T,
       %  BECAUSE WE NEED TO CAPTURE AUTOMATICALLY WITH \par ALONE
\end{myEnv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you are wondering why there is a 5 instead of a 4 for the second paragraph: The line containing the 4 counts as an additional line in the second paragraph.

Comment: Expl3 interfaces manual shows `\cs_set_eq:NN <cs1> <cs2>`, so I would never have guessed there must be colon (`:`) between control sequences. I wonder why this important part is ignored in the manual.

Comment: There is no colon inbetween, the colon belongs to the  one command.

Comment: Commands ending with a colon are functions without arguments. There are a number of such commands in exp3, e.g \group_begin:. Marcel quite correctly added the colon, but as the command is internal it should start with two underscores.